# Don't Starve tag review

Tags: discussion, tags

Don't Starve and its Reign Of Giants 'DLC' have very different mechanics that could impact the answer to a question. In addition, the mechanics of Don't Starve and the ROG DLC are much more different than Don't Starve and Don't Starve Together, yet DST has its own tag (which has only two questions).

Given the amount of different mechanics (wetness, heat, autumn, winter, desert, ice, full moon lighting, tumbleweed, etc.) should Don't Starve Reign Of Giants have its own tag?

And secondly does Don't Starve Together warrant having its own tag given the small number of DST-specific questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reign-of-giants](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reign-of-giants) tag does in fact exist, and is attached to seven questions.

If Don't Starve Together modifies the gameplay in some way, then that's probably a good reason to keep it.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, it does exist, for some reason I didn't notice it on any questions when I searched questions for 'reign of giants'. It seems that while it does exist, it's not being used in a lot of cases where it should be. This is probably either an awareness issue (not many people knowing it exists) or people have looked for the tag under different names and not found it.